# Error using cor.test() but not from cor() in R

Tags: r, correlation

Running `cor()` and `cor.test()` gives me the same p-value in R but `cor.test()` also throws a warning:

```
> cor(diamonds$price, diamonds$carat, method = 'spearman')
[1] 0.9628828
> cor.test(diamonds$price, diamonds$carat, method = 'spearman')

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  diamonds$price and diamonds$carat
S = 9.7086e+11, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.9628828 

Warning message:
In cor.test.default(diamonds$price, diamonds$carat, method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Does this warning effect the p-value and should I not use this test?

Comment: I would say this is not a problem. However, you can find more detailed information regarding this function and its handling of ties in the documentation.